# How to hide all windows except one in macOS?

Tags: macos, window, osx-yosemite, user-interface

I've been using Mac (running Yosemite 10.10) for over a year now and I can't figure one thing out.

I have a lot of windows opened at once usually, then there's a point at which I want to drag & drop something from my desktop to one of these windows (usually the application I'm currently using).

In Windows 7/8 I just click in the right bottom corner of the screen (hides all windows), then I open the application I wanted to use, eventually resize it if it takes the whole screen, drag and drop my stuff on that window, then click the right bottom corner again and all the windows pop up.

In macOS I usually hide/close all the windows on the way, it takes 10x longer than in Windows, then I drag and drop the thing from the desktop. And I end up with all the windows closed.

The question is: Can I somehow hide all windows at once in macOS, except for the one I'm using? If not, can I hide all windows, then just keep them hidden while I open the one window I want to use, then bring everything back as it was?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> will hide all other applications except for the current one. This is the *Hide Others* command, which can be found in the first drop down menu on the menu bar for the application (i.e. *Safari* menu for Safari).

Switching focus to a hidden application, i.e. via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or clicking the icon in the Dock, will unhide the application.

Answer (score -1):

### how *one* of an apps App windows can be raised/lowered

not possible in OSX.

---

The OPs' question appears to be how *one*  of usually many of an apps App windows in a screen can be handled differently from all the others (as in the usual move, or resize, or close or minimize or maximize of *a single window*, which has no effect on *all* (other) of an application's windows. If OSX has any analogue to X-windows 'hide all except the current window' and 'hide the current window' (of only the app presently active which has locator focus) I have yet to find it.

Ability to move, 'push down' 'pull up' 'move to back of window stack' 'move to front of window stack' a *single* window of an app's possibly many windows spanning multiple screens, that facility, moving *only one* of an apps windows in the 'Z' front-to-back order of windows on a display or screen, is *extremely* useful.

Use Case 1:  "I'm done with this *one* window of this app.
but I don't want to close or minimize it"

- push it down or to the back of the windows stack, so it's there but doesn't obscure other apps nor other of that apps' windows except the one that was pushed deeper or to the bottom of the windows stack.

Use Case 2: "I need only *this* (ONE) window of an app,
(I can see it's corner!!)"

- here bringing all (e.g. a dozen finder windows, a dozen browser windows, etc., all forward invoking cmd-H or shift-cmd-H only makes a mess obscuring everything else on the screen;

Bizarrely, trying a work around of minimizing the desired window and then cmd-H results in not only all the apps windows disappearing from screens but also the wanted minimized windows icon disappearing from the Finder bar; shift-cmd-H brings the whole mess back obscuring all other windows onscreen, and all the corresponding minimized windows icons of that app re-appear in the finder bar.

Without ability to move a *single* window in the 'Z' direction of the windows stack means to accomplish either of the above common use-case operations after invoking cmd-H, one must manually locate and bring all the other (now obscured) applications windows forward one by one, restoring the original disposition and order of windows onscreen.
This imposition seems mired in some ancient pre-historic presumption which seems entirely contrary to the vast majority of 'ordinary user' situations where users need work in many (just hit cmd-tab to see how many apps you're using right now) applications simultaneously rather than *only* one application. This faulty presumption also is reflected in facilities like OSX 'Spaces', where in Preferences, applications can be associated with specific spaces.

The single use-case I can think of for cmd-H shift-cmd-H is where a users spends most time in 'all encompassing' multi-windowed apps (think FCP). Otherwise, as above described ctl-cmd-H just causes chaos and extra work and time waste in multi-application desktop situations.

The particular defect in lack of ability to adjust a single window's place in the 'Z' ordering of windows on a desktop has to rank high in the annals of things that will likely never be fixed in OSX.

```
 ------------
```

Additional issues where OSX, Windows, and 'X' have been persistently, over tens of major releases, never repaired, include inability of complete control over a window from except select corners, command stripes or buttons ('decorations' in window-management parlance). Trouble arises when windows get 'trapped' partially or completely out of display space when changes e.g. with present-day screen-sharing, (multiple) displays, resolution adjustments, and Spaces ~ Mission control, etc. are applied. If even a part of window is visible, it may not be able to be resized or moved using that visible  extent. If an app window has somehow ended up at coordinates completely out of display range, it really takes jumping through mind-bending hoops to try and restore it to where it can be used.

Since the QWERTY keyboard, both sides of arguments about implementation, product discrimination, and profit and control motives have increasingly tilted toward unnecessary release churn, incompatibilities, learning-curves, Internetwork dependence, and inconveniences imposed, now on billions of peoples daily lives worldwide. The trend appears increasingly to prevent user control of presentation and interaction.

```
  =============
```

Some would prefer users have no control whatsoever not only of trivial features like window size and aspect ratio, but also of baseline facilities like copy and paste, drag-and-drop, pop-ups, pop-overs, interstitial advertisements, etc., 'screen space' generally is become intermediated by operating environments, windowing systems, Browser, and content providers.
Hugely detrimental to usability, productivity, and incredibly distracting to those trying to stay on-task (why haven't you quit reading this yet???), the sorts of acceptable interaction practices, e.g. my not being able to make a (this) post, for example without authenticating through three different apps (the Web page, login notes, the e-mail and change password, etc. ) and five separate windows, the disorder of never being shown sizes of downloads before actually starting them, inability to control (read:prevent) streaming content, instant popovers before one has had even half a second to view a Web page, simple total loss of control of imposed by malevolent web pages, these and many other 'techniques'  ~ obfuscation of texts, impossibly tedious interactions (e.g with maps displayed on wristwatches) and other hyper-constraints (the vogues of SMS-length messages   and 7-second videos where no real technical limitations exist) defaults of mass-publication, and 'shaping' of interaction- and search- results - Volumes could be written on the circuses of ways to corral and heard populations. In a benign world, the zenith of evolution of all this, the electronic opiate of the  masses - would be Television.

We're far beyond that.

[ maximum post length exceeded? ]